# Уточняющие обстоятельства времени

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли здесь выделять запятыми обстоятельство времени "в 30-е годы" или наречие "затем" примыкает к нему?

Затем в 30-е годы из этих же порошков стали изготавливать буровой инструмент.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Видимо, по смыслу 30-е годы следуют за периодом, о котором говорилось перед этим - тогда "в 30-е годы" нужно выделять запятыми как уточнение (вот какой период имеется в виду под "затем"). Если этого не сделать, "затем" будет относиться к следующему по порядку событию того же периода "30-е годы": как будто перед этим уже говорилось, что в 30-е годы сначала делалось что-то другое (ср. "затем в том веке наступило затишье в войнах").

Comment: Спасибо большое.